# TypeScript make param optional if not provided

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have this interface:

```
export interface IScene<R extends string> {
  path: R;
  params?: SceneParams;
}
```

SceneParams interface:

```
export interface SceneParams {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

This works totally fine when I create a scene like:

```
interface PostDetailScene extends IScene<PostRoute.Detail> {
  params: PostDetailSceneParams;
}
```

PostDetailSceneParams:

```
export interface PostDetailSceneParams extends SceneParams {
  postId: string;
}
```

All these code gets correct type checking:

```
// CORRECT
getPathWithParams({
  path: PostRoute.Detail,
  params: { postId: '4' },
});

getPathWithParams({
  path: UserRoute.List,
});

getPathWithParams({
  path: UserRoute.List,
  params: undefined,
});

// ERROR
getPathWithParams({
  path: PostRoute.Detail,
  params: undefined,
});

getPathWithParams({
  path: PostRoute.Detail,
});

getPathWithParams({
  path: UserRoute.List,
  params: { wrongParam: 'value' },
});
```

Now I have a scene where I don't want to pass any props. This scene is the UserListScene:

```
interface UserListScene extends IScene<UserRoute.List> {
  params?: never;
}
```

You see I have to explicitly type `params?: never` (or `params?: undefined` - I also don't know which type I should use here because here the params would/should really never get passed - but with `never` the compiler gets also satisfied with undefined so I don't see that much difference)

My question is: Is there a solution for changing the IScene interface so that I don't have to type `params?: never` or `params?: undefined` when there are no params for this scene?

I just want to write:

```
interface UserListScene extends IScene<UserRoute.List> {}
```

or:

```
type UserListScene = IScene<UserRoute.List>;
```

**EDIT:**

This function should also get correct type checking:

```
export function getPathWithParams(scene: Scene): string {
  if (!scene.params) {
    return scene.path;
  }

  let pathWithParams: string = scene.path;
  const paramsAsString = Object.keys(scene.params);

  paramsAsString.forEach((param: string) => {
    pathWithParams = pathWithParams.replace(`:${param}`, scene.params[param]);
  });

  return pathWithParams;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two interfaces (as truly that is what you really have here):

```
export interface IScene<R extends string> {
  path: R;
}

export interface ISceneWithParams<R extends string> {
  path: R;
  params: SceneParams;
}
```

Comment: But then I have to decide between to interfaces every time I create a Scene. I just want to have one interface for both cases. Also, I edited my answer and add a function that should also get correct type checking.